# What is the advantage of pluggable database over normal databases?

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

Why creating pluggable database over normal database is good for system performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a performance gain, but multi-tenant architecture reduces hardware costs.

http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/cdbovrvw.htm#CEGJGEJH